# How set header in scaladsl?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am trying to make a test for a scaladsl route. My route code is:

```
class EmployeeRoutes (implicit logger: LoggingAdapter) extends JsonSupport {
val route : Route = post {
    path("employee" / "echo") {
        logger.info("Message recived")
        entity(as[Employee]) { employee =>
            val idItem = employee.id
            val nameItem = employee.name
            complete((StatusCodes.OK, s"Employee {$idItem} is $nameItem."))
       }
    }
  }
}
```

And, my test is:

```
class EmployeeRoutesTest extends WordSpec with Matchers with ScalatestRouteTest {
    implicit val logger = Logging(system, getClass)
    val employeeRoutes = new EmployeeRoutes()
    val employeeRoute = employeeRoutes.route
    val echoPostRequest = Post("/employee/echo", "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"John\"}")

    "The service" should {
        "return a Employee {1} is John message for POST request with {\"id\":1,\"name\":\"John\"}" in {
            echoPostRequest ~> Route.seal(employeeRoute) ~> check {
                status == StatusCodes.OK
                responseAs[String] shouldEqual "Employee {1} is John"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But, I always get following error running my test:

```
"[The request's Content-Type is not supported. Expected:
application/jso]n" did not equal "[Employee {1} is Joh]n"
ScalaTestFailureLocation: routes.EmployeeRoutesTest at (EmployeeRoutesTest.scala:30)
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: "[The request's Content-Type is not supported. Expected:
application/jso]n" did not equal "[Employee {1} is Joh]n"
at org.scalatest.MatchersHelper$.indicateFailure(MatchersHelper.scala:340)
at org.scalatest.Matchers$AnyShouldWrapper.shouldEqual(Matchers.scala:6742)
```

How can I set "application/json" header in scaladsl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When putting together your POST request using Akka-HTTP testkit, you're just passing in a String. Akka has no way to decide whether to interpret that as a JSON, or to keep that a String.

You can enforce a specific content type when tailoring your `HttpEntity` using

```
val echoPostRequest = Post(
  "/employee/echo", 
  HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, """{"id":1, "name":"John"}""")
)
```

PS: the triple quotes help you avoid escape-slash mayhem.